# Converting an Integer to NSData in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

In Objective-C the code looked liked this,

```
    NSInteger random = arc4random_uniform(99) + 1 
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:& random length: sizeof(random)];
```

But when I try to do this in Swift,

```
    let random:NSInteger = NSInteger(arc4random_uniform(99) + 1) //(1-100)
    let data = NSData(bytes: &random, length: 3)
```

It gives me an error staying that "NSInteger is not convertible to @lvalue inout $T1

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which line do you actually get that on?  The first one looks a bit weird to me (although I haven't done anything much in Swift yet).  Try `Int` instead of `NSInteger`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am getting the error when I declare the data variable in Swift. The Objective-C way is indeed funky but it works!

Comment: BTW `sizeof(random)` can be 4 or 8 but never be 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're going to send a pointer to a variable as a parameter in this way, the variable needs to be mutable (that is, declared with `var`), since the receiving function or method will be able to directly modify the variable. The code you want is:

```
var random = NSInteger(arc4random_uniform(99) + 1) //(1-100)
let data = NSData(bytes: &random, length: 3)
```

You can read more about using `UnsafePointer<Void>` in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_14).

Comment: `length: 3` looks suspicious :)

Comment: very suspicious