# Transform Int to NSData

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, characteristics

Hi guys I need to write a value from my iPhone to an BLE peripheral.

The service and characteristic is discovered and the connection is also there.

PROBLEM:
I need to write the value 2 to the characteristic. 
For that I call

```
peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristic, 
type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
```

data should be 2 but it should be from Type NSData.
My conversion from int to NSData has the result **02000000** and not **2**, the characteristic needs 2.

What is wrong in this conversion? How can I get NSData with value **2**

```
    var ring = 2

    //Convert 2 to NSData -> for peripheral.writeValue()
    let data = NSData(bytes: &ring, length: sizeof(NSInteger))

    //---> let data is <02000000> should be <2>
    print(data)
```

The following Code is context where I need the value 2 in NSData

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

    var data1 = characteristic.descriptors

    //print("\(data1.dynamicType)")
    //print(data1)
    var ring = 2

    //Convert 2 to NSData -> for peripheral.writeValue()
    let data = NSData(bytes: &ring, length: sizeof(NSInteger))//sizeof(NSInteger))

    //---> let data is <02000000> should be <2>
    print(data)


    //Write Datat to peripheral ( characteristic )
    peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)

}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
    print("Value is Written")

}
```

Thank you a lot.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24653879/195691

Comment: You may want to see if this answer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227066/converting-an-integer-to-nsdata-in-swift#26227247.